# h 264 Hardware encoding /decoding For IOS(IPhone/Ipad)?

Tags: iphone, ios, avfoundation, h.264

i have done Real time video processing in ios using AVFoundation framework ,
help of [this link](http://www.benjaminloulier.com/articles/ios4-and-direct-access-to-the-camera).i have tested it is working fine. now i want to use h264 encoding and decoding[Before draw] .i try to get h264 encoded data from AVCaptureSession ,so i have set AVVideoCodecH264 in AVCaptureSession's videosetting,before Start capturing .

> NSDictionary* videoSettings = [NSDictionary
>   dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:value,key,AVVideoCodecH264,AVVideoCodecKey,
>   nil];
>   [captureOutput setVideoSettings:videoSettings];

above code doesn't produce any change in output buffer,same buffer format get as like before. how to accomplish my requirement ? is it possible ? if so Please Help me to getting started ,h264 in ios.

Comment: am looking for armv7 device ...

Comment: @Asta: Did the answer given by Daniel work for you? If no then how did you finally solve this?

Answer (score 1):

There's no direct access to encoded keyframes. You may found some insightful comments about that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4399162/how-to-stream-live-video-from-iphone-to-a-media-server-like-wowza

A pair `AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoCodecKey` may be used as parameters in `outputSettings` in

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *outputSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoCodecKey, nil];

AVAssetWriterInput *assetWriterInput = [[AVAssetWriterInput alloc]
                                   initWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo
                                      outputSettings:outputSettings];
AVAssetWriter *assetWriter = [[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:fileURL
                                                       fileType:AVFileTypeMPEG4
                                                          error:&error];
if (!error && [assetWriter canAddInput:assetWriterInput])
  [assetWriter addInput:assetWriterInput];
```